# Where to place DefferedScripts of kendo grid when using it with RequireJs

Tags: .net, kendo-ui, requirejs, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I tried to initialize Kendo grid with the helpers. I have it like this in an .cshtml file that is rendered in Layout.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<FeatureViewModel>()
                .Name("testGrid")
                .Columns(column =>
                        {
                            column.Bound(c => c.Id);
                            column.Bound(c => c.Name);
                            column.Bound(c => c.Type);
                        })
                .Scrollable()
                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                            .Refresh(true)
                            .PageSizes(true)
                            .ButtonCount(1))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .Read(read => read.Action("Features", "Feature")))
                .Deferred(true)

)
@section scripts{

<script>
    require(["jquery","kendoCore", "kendoGrid", "js/Product/index"], function ($,core,grid) {
           @(Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts())
    });
</script>

}
```

But now I get an error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I know that I'm not supposed to put that defferedscripts there but I tried some variations of this and it didn't work. Either "kendo is not defined" or this error. If anybody had this problem before and solved it and could give me some guidance it would be awesome.